# C++ Native Win32 simple Edit Control

Tags: c++, winapi, native

I'm currently experimenting with making a little native Win32 executable. So no external libraries/wrappers/frameworks. I added a simple edit control and a button. The problem is that I can't change the text of an Edit Control in the Properties window of Visual Studio. The default text is `Sample edit box` and that doesn't show up in the Properties window (IDC_EDIT1), so I can't change it.

How can I change the text of an Edit Control (preferably within the properties window)? Also, is an edit control part of the MFC library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio's *Properties* window is part of the graphical UI to create and modify [Resource Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599.aspx). Resource files are used, among other things, to store dialog templates, including the dialog's child controls. Since the [EDITTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381009.aspx) resource statement doesn't allow for an initial text entry, you cannot statically set one. You will have to set the control text at runtime, either by using the [Edit_SetText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb849159.aspx) macro, or by calling [SetWindowText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546.aspx) directly.

The [Edit Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458.aspx) is a standard Windows control, not part of MFC. MFC provides a wrapper class, [CEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7yhsd2b.aspx), like it does for all other standard controls.

Comment: It's an odd limitation of the resource script language, since the control itself uses the title passed to `CreateWindowEx` as its initial value quite happily.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: The edit control is predominantly used purely as a user input control. Setting an initial value is usually not required. For those rare cases, where an initial value is required, it can be set at runtime. What's more common is setting a cue banner ([Edit_SetCueBannerText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761701.aspx)). But that was invented long after the resource script language had been published.

Answer (score 0):

In your dialog window function use this construct to set text for your control (given its id is ID_BUTTON)

```
BOOL CALLBACK  DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
     switch (iMsg)
     {
          case WM_INITDIALOG :
               SetDlgItemText ( hDlg, ID_BUTTON, "Button Text" );
               return TRUE ;
     }
     return FALSE ;
}
```